# App shouldnt start at Bootup BUT starting

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have this device administrator priviledge app with some ,broadcasters (which I'm duely registering and UNregistering at the right time!) ,The problem is that my app starts on device boot and I don't have any intent that filters this intent and makes my app start! ,Please see the AndroidManifest.xml  as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.winacro.xyz"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<!--uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /-->
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Fullscreen" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.winacro.xyz.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Fullscreen" >

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.winacro.xyz.Boot"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.winacro.xyz.Xyz"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Fullscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.winacro.xyz.Locked"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Fullscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />


    <service
        android:name="com.winacro.xyz.xyzService"
        android:enabled="true" > 

    </service>

    <receiver android:name="com.winacro.xyz.MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </receiver>

     <receiver android:name="com.winacro.xyz.activateSERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </receiver>

    <!-- Device Admin Receiver -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.winacro.xyz.DeviceAdminR"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- This action is required -->
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- This is required this receiver to become device admin component. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/policies" />
    </receiver>

</application>
```

As you can see I have the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED commented in manifest as such it should route the Boot event to my but still my app starts from the activateSERVICE.java which goes as follows:

```
public class activateSERVICE extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Boolean Set True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Intent startActSerIntent = new Intent(context, Boot.class);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("com.winacro.xyz", "com.winacro.xyz.Boot");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Intent startService = new Intent(context, xyzService.class);
    context.startService(startService);
    context.startActivity(i);
    //context.startActivity(startActSerIntent);
    xyzService.USBpluggedIn = true;
}
```

}

PLease tell me why my app starts?(I'm confirmed that my app starts from activateSERVICE is because of the reason that only this code sets the variable USBpluggedIn = true; and only if this is set that my app starts xyzService.class which is starting. )

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED broadcast because some USB device is attached to device at boot time.

Comment: NO it pops up still, even without any USB device connected, the solution isn't that easy.

Comment: Have you looked at the logs? And examine Intent passed to your receiver, this should contain info about what triggered broadcast.

Comment: Ya I did but maybe I'll pay again attention to logs, The problem is that this happens when phone starts and the app immidiately opens on boot and by that time ADB isn't activated so can't use the LOGCAT!

Comment: What does the intent contain?

Comment: I see. If all else fails create a plain file in your onreceive and write your info there. Then you can pull this file later.

Comment: you mean write to a text file the logcat contents or what?

Comment: In your onReceive method extract and write to some file contents of received intent. This should give you an idea what triggers this receiver.